# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una suma en un each de javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una lista de números pero no se como sumarlos usando un each
alguien sabe como? Saludos y que tenga un feliz domingo.

```
$(response).each(function(i,v){
                          console.log(parseInt(v.calificacion))
                          var $num = parseInt(v.calificacion)
                          console.log($num)
                        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] <- Así obtengo mis números enteros.

Comment: para sumar totales va mejor un [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), con el each tenes que guardar el acumulado por fuera asi no se pisa en cada iteración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sumar un arreglo de numeros puedes usar la funcion `reduce` de javascript de la siguiente forma:

```js
const arregloNumeros = [3, 8, 6, 9];

// 0(valor inicial) + 3 + 8 + 6 + 9
const valorInicial = 0;
const sumaTotal = arregloNumeros.reduce(
  (acumulador, valorActual) => acumulador + valorActual,
  valorInicial
);

console.log(sumaTotal);
// resultado: 26
```

Como puedes observar la función `reduce` nos permite sumar un arreglo de números sin modificar el arreglo original te dejo mas información acerca de la función reduce [aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Lo pongo adentro del each no?

Comment: No, es asi tal cual como lo escribi, no necesitas each para iterar porque lo haces con reduce.

Comment: Muchas gracias.